# accessing shared network using at

Tags: windows

I have a program which I would like to run every X min

the problem is that the program is accessing a shared network and using AT command I can't use it (due to the fact that AT is running the program with SYSTEM ACCOUNT)

any ideas how to slove this issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the /interactive switch buy you what you want?

"Use this parameter to allow the task to interact with the desktop of the user who is logged on at the time the task runs."

For more info see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565

With the at command your options are either to run as the System user or the user which is currently logged on.

You might want to try having your program run as a scheduled task instead. That would give you the option to run under any account in which you have credentials (username/password). You can either set this up manually, through the control panel, or programatically from C# [using this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx)